# Input box with drop down items

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, xamarin, textfield

In Xamarin, how can I develop an input box that when the user inputs text, a dropdown list/menu appears with items that the user can click on?

What type of input control do I need, and how do I code the dropdown list?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the combination of EditText and ListView to perform this. Refer this Link [Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/) for more details.

Comment: That's java. Xamarin tag implies C#.